# cocos2d and box2d .. creating map and worlds

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

So my question is really about creating different levels in my game. I am using cocos2d and box2d and right now I have a lot of code that actually constructs my world and I can't do pane or stuff like that coz honestly i don't know how..

So any tips and pointers for beginner to create world with static object and then I can add my own sprite to that world and move around with box2d?

Answer (score 0):

Start running through the tutorials for Cocos2D.  All of them.  Modify them to see changes your interested in.  I can think of a number of ways you might be able to construct your levels but it wouldn't necessarily make sense if you are not familiar with the Cocos2D classes and terminology.  Try posting your question on the [Cocos2D forums](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/) as well.  Possibly someone in the Cocos2D community has already done this.